# Backbone Forms hidden field not rendering

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js

I am trying render a form using powmedia backbone-forms, and am not seeing it being generated in my markup. My model schema looks like this:

```
schema: {
    name: {
        title: 'Report Name',
        validators: ['required'],
        fieldClass: 'ui-fieldset-1'
    },
    organization_id: {
        type: 'Hidden'
    },
}
```

The name field shows fine, but the organization_id field isn't visible in my source. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you having this problem? https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/pull/75

Comment: I don't believe so. I have an up to date copy of the distribution. on ln 207, i see `if (itemSchema.type != 'Hidden') { $fieldsContainer.append(fieldEl); }` I think that they moved things around a bit since that merge, but the code looks right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I was not using the built in:

```
form.getValue()
```

Instead, I was using another plugin called Backbone Syphon to serialize my data, which wasn't playing nice. It also appears that hidden inputs are not included in the source on purpose. Because Backbone is stateless by design, it is easier to store hidden input values in a JavaScript object int he browser. See Charlie's comment here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/backbone-forms/BWvsEMVHC6I